# How to scale the screen area smaller on mobile phones only

Tags: construct-2

How to scale the layout/screen smaller on mobile phones?

I know Project Settings / FULL SCREEN IN BROWSER setting fixes scaling issue on phone, but I don't want to open my game always in Full Screen, full screen is necessary only on small size mobile phones.

Can I somehow check the screen resolution on start of layout  and adjust the size of layout runtime?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but maybe for the next guy:

You could use a system condition to compare WindowWidth
or WindowHeight.  If it is under a certain threshold, maybe 1024, then use the Browser object to request FullScreen in an action.

Personally, I would expect the app to run full screen on touch devices, so I use the touch object for On Any Touch and then request full screen using the Browser object.

Note: To request full screen, there must be a user action, so you need to put your request inside an event for a button press, tap, etc.  Anything generated by the user.